# Adding to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

My program end result is to take information from a gui (date and temperature) and then have it saved to a pandas dataframe. This dataframe will then be sent to excel and I will eventually run some calculations on it. I have gotten to the point where one execution of data from the gui is sent to excel. But on B2 and C2 are ever changed in the excel. Everytime I exceute the code I want the dataframe to be updated with whatever result was user inputted. Is someone able to help with this. I do not know all of python syntax so an explination as to what you are doing would be nice so that I might understand it and learn from it.

```
#imports 
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk

#creating window 
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Entry Form")
window.geometry("600x600")

#creating pandas dataset
myData = {
    "date":[], 
    "temperature": [] 
}
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(myData)

#methods
def enterbtn(df:pd.DataFrame):
    date = dateEntry.get()
    temperature = tempEntry.get()
    new_row = {"date": date, "temperature": temperature}
    df.loc[len(df)] = new_row
    dataFrame.to_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
    window.destroy()




#actual GUIs
tk.Label(window, text = "Please enter a temperature and date, thank you!", font = ("Calibri", 20, "bold")).grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 2)
tk.Label(window, text = "Temperature:", font = ("Calibri", 10)).grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = "e")
tempEntry = tk.Entry(window, font = ("Calibri", 10))
tempEntry.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = "w")
tk.Label(window, text = "Date:", font = ("Calibri", 10)).grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky = "e")
dateEntry = tk.Entry(window, font = ("Calibri", 10))
dateEntry.grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky = "w")
button1 = tk.Button(window, text = "Enter", font = ("Calibri", 10), command = lambda:enterbtn(df=dataFrame) )
button1.grid(column = 0, row = 3, columnspan = 2)

#run window
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).